# What Photogrammetry software is available on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, maps

I have been searching for a [photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) application for Mac. 
Can anyone tell me where can I get them?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

- [VisualSFM](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/) is a GUI application for 3D reconstruction using structure from motion (SFM).
- [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) is an open source, portable, and extensible system for the processing and editing of unstructured 3D triangular meshes.
- [bundler_sfm](https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm) is a structure-from-motion system for unordered image collections.
- [123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) is a free app that lets you create 3D scans of virtually any object.
- [openMVG](https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG/) is a library for computer-vision scientists and especially targeted to the Multiple View Geometry community.

Several more here:

- Open Source Photogrammetry: Ditching 123D Catch
- http://wedidstuff.heavyimage.com/index.php/2013/07/12/open-source-photogrammetry-workflow/

and here:

- Software - Photogrammetric Vision Lab
- http://www.photogrammetric-vision.com/software.html